Application Pools does not start after system restart - starting manually with the same credentials works
I hope maybe some of you had similar issue with IIS and Application Pools.
Problem that I have is that when I do the restart of the machine my Application Pools are not started and I have to do that manually every single time.
If I go to check logs in Event Viewer (Windows Logs -> System) and I can see on system start error logs saying:
"Application pool MY_POOL_NAME has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application pool because the application pool identity is invalid."
and instantly after that:
"Application pool MY_POOL_NAME has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool."
Then if I open IIS and do this manually by clicking right click button on that Pool and click Start - everything works properly and Pool is started without problems. I'm not changing anything so credentials to that user are up to date and correct.
I have already read about that problem but nothing helps, for example:
Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool
and
https://community.spiceworks.com/t/application-pool-cannot-auto-start/559860

This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this, you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@samwu ok, thanks for w tip, I will try that for sure. But do I need to configure this tool somehow? Or I just need to run it, restart my machine and look into generated file what happened?

@samwu are you able to help how to analyze logs from dump somehow?

You can refer to this this link: How to use the Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot a process that has stopped responding in IIS and How to Use Debug Diagnostics to Analyze a Memory Dump.
